# Nichrome powder acting as a resistor

Tags: resistors, resistance, conductivity, materials

I’ve been doing some experiments recently with metal powders and I’m wondering if someone can help me interpret the results and give me some advice.

I wanted to test how the metal powder would work in a circuit. I tested some graphite powder and some nichrome powder.

I made a circuit using two AAA 1.5 V batteries in series and some PVC insulated solid core 1.5 mm diameter copper wire. I pulled some of the PVC insulation off the copper wire a little and then packed some metal powder into the tube. Next I pushed another copper wire into the tube.  This made two pieces of copper wire connected by some densely packed powder.  I then tested the amps running through the circuit using a multimeter.

The results were -

Control circuit (using only copper wire - no powder) 400 micro amps

Graphite circuit 10 micro amps

Nichrome circuit 0 micro amps

What happened here? Obviously the graphite has a much higher conductivity than the nichrome. Is the nichrome acting as a resistor in my circuit?

How can I get my circuit to run using the nichrome powder?  Do I need to increase the amps with the batteries in parallel, or the volts with the batteries in series?

I know the conductivity of the nichrome in relation to the graphite - can I calculate how much more power is needed in the circuit based on a comparison of the conductivity of the two materials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nichrome develops a passivation layer on its outer surface. That's what prevents it from oxidizing any further. Would a batch of nichrome powder even be conductive with so much surface area to oxidize?

Comment: Thanks DKNguyen, so are you saying that the nichrome powder is not conductive at all?

Comment: @EddieP I don't know. I only learned from your post that nichrome powder was actually a thing that existed at all. The finer your powder is, the more of it will be chromium oxide. Now, I am not sure if the passivation layer forms only when the metal gets red hot or if it is already there at room temperature.

Comment: I will have to check with the maker. Apparently it is not usually used for conducting electricity, so it may be that it is not conductive.

Comment: What is it supposed to be used for, anyways?

Comment: I was thinking of mixing the powder with epoxy and screen printing it onto a substrate to make small patterns that could be heated. Sounds crazy now that I say it

Comment: I meant, what is it normally supposed to be used for. I don't see why you couldn't just use carbon for your purposes. It's not like it's going to be able to get nichrome hot with the epoxy there anyways. Were you planning on mixing the powders in different ratios or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111628/discussion-between-eddiep-and-dknguyen).